# Convert XLS file to XLSX in talend

Tags: java, excel, postgresql, talend, file-conversion

When I am loading an excel file from a remote server, I am facing an error in talend : “Unable to recognize OLE stream”. Can I convert this file from xls to xlsx in talend? I tried by renaming the extension to xlsx in the tFileInputconvert but it doesn't read then. I can convert to xlsx by saving it as xlsx but the file is on some server through which the data is being loaded into the postgresql tables. Is it possible to convert this file to xlsx or write some java code in talend to make it "Save as" xlsx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as stated above. Here is the screen and its error :

[image]

Error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To convert from XLS to XLSX in Talend

Use a tFileInputExcel to read the XLS file, leaving the option for xlsx unchecked . Define the tabs to read, schema, etc.

Send the output to the component below, or add a tLogRow in the middle to see the rows retrieved from the first step.

Use a tFileOutoutExcel to write those rows of data to a new file, with extension XLSX and having the XLSX option selected .

Comment: From your screen shot , it says it cannot find the file and it looks to me like there is an extra between the path and the file name log.xls . That would cause a problem

Comment: I have modified that in the image. The path is not the issue. The file gets loaded when it is converted to xlsx, but the issue is that the file is on a remote server with xls(old version of excel), so need to get it in xlsx in order to load the data

Comment: If the error message in your screenshot is accurate, it would indicate a path or file name related issue.  I suggest breaking this down into very simple pieces to get it working correctly, in concept, and then use those techniques on the real thing. Try creating a fresh, dummy XLS file in a simple location like c:\tmp\file.xls. Give it a single column col1, with two rows of values . Then use the Talend component to read it, log it, finally write a new file as XLSX

Comment: It works when I create a fresh dummy file, but then the file which I have is on a remote server in xls older excel version format which the talend cannot read it (Unable to recognize OLE stream”). Hence the need to convert the file into xls windows xp version/xlsx format so that talend can read it. The issue clearly shows that the component cannot open the excel file which means the path is not an issue but the file format is an issue.The inbuild excel api cannot read that. Any way to convert this file to xlsx through java or something else in talend?

Comment: The Talend Excel components use the Apache POI library for working with Excel files. Per the POI documentation, it states that it supports Excel files version 97-2008. What version of Excel format is your source file?  You could try an alternative library which can read formats older than 10 years ago.  You could write your own. You could find a converter program which works.  Or, you could upgrade other parts of the system to work with newer formats, etc.

See docs https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Ok Thanks.. How can I write my own code? Save file as xlsx code ? I can't code, if you can help.

Comment: Apache POI   is approximately 410,000 lines of code. So, writing something similar is beyond the scope of what of we can do in this Q&A forum.    https://www.openhub.net/p/poi    Thank you and good luck

Comment: Can we add this api into talend or only that api which can support old xls version ? or maybe use tlibraryload to load the jar if possible ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am unable to help you further on this.